# How to get the directory name with opendir()?

Tags: c, linux, stat, opendir

I want to take the name of a directory by command line with function `opendir()`, but I don't know how...
I have implemented the function `do_ls` and I'm trying to pass the name of the directory giving by command line as an argument.

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <dirent.h>
#include    <sys/stat.h>
#include    <string.h>

void do_ls(char *);
void dostat(char *);
void show_file_info( char *, struct stat *);
void mode_to_letters( int , char [] );
char *uid_to_name( uid_t );
char *gid_to_name( gid_t );


int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    if ( ac == 1 )
        do_ls( "." );
    else
        while ( --ac ){
            printf("%s:\n", *++av );
            do_ls( *av );
        }
    return 0;
}


void do_ls( char argv[] )
/*
 *  list files in directory called dirname
 */
{
    DIR     *dir_ptr;       
    struct dirent   *direntp;       

    if ( ( dir_ptr = opendir( argv[0]) ) == NULL )
        fprintf(stderr,"ls2: cannot open %s\n", argv[0]);
    else
    {
        while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL ) {
            if (strcmp(direntp->d_name,".")==0 ||
                strcmp(direntp->d_name,"..")==0) continue;
            dostat( direntp->d_name );
        }
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
}


void dostat( char *filename )
{
    struct stat info;

    if ( stat(filename, &info) == -1 )      /* cannot stat   */
        perror( filename );         /* say why   */
    else                    /* else show info    */
        show_file_info( filename, &info );
}


void show_file_info( char *filename, struct stat *info_p )
/*
 * display the info about 'filename'.  The info is stored in struct at *info_p
 */
{
    char    *uid_to_name(), *ctime(), *gid_to_name(), *filemode();
    void    mode_to_letters();
        char    modestr[11];

    mode_to_letters( info_p->st_mode, modestr );

    printf( "%s"    , modestr );
    printf( "%4d "  , (int) info_p->st_nlink);  
    printf( "%-8s " , uid_to_name(info_p->st_uid) );
    printf( "%-8s " , gid_to_name(info_p->st_gid) );
    printf( "%8ld " , (long)info_p->st_size);
    printf( "%.12s ", 4+ctime(&info_p->st_mtime));
    printf( "%s\n"  , filename );

}

/*
 * utility functions
 */

/*
 * This function takes a mode value and a char array
 * and puts into the char array the file type and the 
 * nine letters that correspond to the bits in mode.
 * NOTE: It does not code setuid, setgid, and sticky
 * codes
 */

void mode_to_letters( int mode, char str[] )
{
    strcpy( str, "----------" );           /* default=no perms */

    if ( S_ISDIR(mode) )  str[0] = 'd';    /* directory?       */
    if ( S_ISCHR(mode) )  str[0] = 'c';    /* char devices     */
    if ( S_ISBLK(mode) )  str[0] = 'b';    /* block device     */

    if ( mode & S_IRUSR ) str[1] = 'r';    /* 3 bits for user  */
    if ( mode & S_IWUSR ) str[2] = 'w';
    if ( mode & S_IXUSR ) str[3] = 'x';

    if ( mode & S_IRGRP ) str[4] = 'r';    /* 3 bits for group */
    if ( mode & S_IWGRP ) str[5] = 'w';
    if ( mode & S_IXGRP ) str[6] = 'x';

    if ( mode & S_IROTH ) str[7] = 'r';    /* 3 bits for other */
    if ( mode & S_IWOTH ) str[8] = 'w';
    if ( mode & S_IXOTH ) str[9] = 'x';
}

#include    <pwd.h>

char *uid_to_name( uid_t uid )
/* 
 *  returns pointer to username associated with uid, uses getpw()
 */ 
{
    struct  passwd *getpwuid(), *pw_ptr;
    static  char numstr[10];

    if ( ( pw_ptr = getpwuid( uid ) ) == NULL ){
        sprintf(numstr,"%d", uid);
        return numstr;
    }
    else
        return pw_ptr->pw_name ;
}

#include    <grp.h>

char *gid_to_name( gid_t gid )
/*
 *  returns pointer to group number gid. used getgrgid(3)
 */
{
    struct group *getgrgid(), *grp_ptr;
    static  char numstr[10];

    if ( ( grp_ptr = getgrgid(gid) ) == NULL ){
        sprintf(numstr,"%d", gid);
        return numstr;
    }
    else
        return grp_ptr->gr_name;
}
```

Comment: Note that `dostat()` needs to be told the directory name as well as the name of the file in the directory; otherwise it will fail to find the file unless the name of the directory is `.` (dot, the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
( argv[0])
```

is extracting the first char from the passed parameter.

suggest:

```
( argv )
```

so getting a pointer to the NUl terminated string that was passed to the function.

Comment: This is one problem for sure, and the compiler should be telling the OP about this mistake.  It is important to pay attention to compiler warnings, and if you have compiler warnings when you post code, say so — it makes people less cross because they don't have to spend time working out what's up with the code.